# Embeding websites in HTML/Webkit2

Tags: html, gtk, webkit, gtk3, webkit2

Im trying to build simple browser using only HTML in GTK WebView2 (without any other widgets).

The code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input value="https://www.google.com" onchange="document.querySelector('iframe').src=this.value;"><br>
        <iframe  src="https://www.google.com" width="300" height="200"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I cant get many pages (such as google.com) to load due to `'X-Frame-Options' set to 'sameorigin'`. (I understand this is for security reasons and i dont want to use any hacky solutions.)

Is there a way to tell the WebKit to load the page into the existing html and treat it like separate webview or do i have to use two webviews (one for UI and one for websites)?